# How can I protect myself and my game from users including copyrighted material in the content they submit?

Tags: copyright

For example there is a Warcraft III map with *Tom & Jerry* in it. The author clearly doesn't have the rights for it.

How can I avoid getting into trouble for user-submitted content like this being hosted on my servers?

Is a statement regarding this in the EULA enough or what?

Comment: Asking how X is doing Y is off-topic for the site. I reworded the question so that it could apply to someone developing a game.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has been asked before. If you feel that the other question (and answers) does not answer your question, then please edit it and highlight the differences.